# Counting terms in recursive operation

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, combinatorics, algebra

Suppose $X$ is an algebra and $T :X\to X$ is linear function. Let $L:X\to X$ be a  function satisfying the following property
$$L(a \cdot b)= T(a)\cdot b + a \cdot T(b)+b\cdot T(a)+T(b)\cdot a\tag{*}$$
Now, I am interested in counting the terms of this kind of expansion for a nested application of $L$; that is, I want to know how many terms are in $$L(a_1\cdot L(a_2\cdots L(a_{n-2}\cdot L(a_{n-1}\cdot a_n))\cdots). \tag{**}$$
In particular, (*) shows that for $n=2$, we have four terms. I want to write a program for which $n$ is specified  and gives me the number of terms of the decomposition of $(**)$. For the sake of example, the expression $(***)$ with $n=3$ looks like $L(a_1\cdot L(a_2\cdot a_3)).$

I am not interested in the form of the decomposition itself, only on the number of terms. Taking into account that two similar terms will merge into a single term, e.g. $a\cdot T(b)+a\cdot T(b)=2aT(b)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to just work it out. First let's implement a version of `L` using `NonComutativeMultiply`:

```
L[a_, b_] := Plus @@ Map[
   Distribute[#, Plus, NonCommutativeMultiply]&,
   {T[a] ** b, a ** T[b], b ** T[a], T[b] ** a}
]
```

The `Distribute` makes sure that all the multiplications are expanded out. By using `Plus`, identical terms will be grouped together automatically, so there's no need to worry about that.

Next, you can generate the nested `L` expression with a `Fold` and then just take the length:

```
Fold[L[a[#2], #1] &, a[1], Range[2, 10]] // Length
```

> 1534

You can get the sequence of lengths with `FoldList` (throwing away the first element `a[1]` of the sequence):

```
Length /@ Rest[FoldList[L[a[#2], #1] &, a[1], Range[2, 10]]]
```

> {4, 10, 22, 46, 94, 190, 382, 766, 1534}

## Bonus

As a bonus, it looks like the series can be fitted with a fairly simple formula (which is probably not too surprising):

```
FindSequenceFunction[%, n]
```

> -2 + 3 * 2^n